# Creature that can choose all options in its timeline

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, magical-creatures, animals, timeline

I am trying to find a very short story that I read when I was a kid in the 80s, and it is most probably decades older. It was only a paragraph or two long, and it just described an animal or creature (not quite a a full narrative) that could choose all the options that life presented it with, therefore its timeline rather than linear became round with all the alternative lifelines developing their own branches, which developed more branches, and so on. I think the creature had a name, and it may have been the work of a philosopher rather than a story writer, but I cannot remember or find it again. I thought it was by Kafka, as I used to read many short stories by him, but after searching his work I cannot locate a creature like this on his stories. Any leads??

Comment: It sounds like something from one of the later Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy books, probably *Mostly Harmless*, but it was played for comedy in that.

Comment: Similar to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Man